# How to solve this Error #1064. while creating function

Tags: mysql

**This is My function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))

RETURNS VARCHAR(255)

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
    SET input = LOWER(input);
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET input = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(input,i),
                    UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
                );
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN input;
END;
```

I am using this function to get first letter capital of each word , But it is giving me an error .I searched for solution and i found some solutions also but they are not working.

**MySQL** said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the solution This i new code which is working properly .

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  FUNCTION `db_name`.`Ucfirst`(`word` VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(word);
    SET word = LOWER(word);
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(word,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET word = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(word,i),
                    UPPER(MID(word,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(word,len - i - 1)
                );
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN word;
     END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

semicolons are missing:

```
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

RETURN input;
```