# in PhpMyAdmin call stored procedures is ok but running as a query doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures

this is my store procedure in mysql .when i call it in phpmyadmin its ok and done 
call in phpmyadmin
**CALL sp_del_temp_record('tbl_user_login_and',1880,10)**
but when i use in mysql_query it is not working:
mysql_query("CALL sp_del_temp_record('tbl_user_login_and',1877,10)");
this is my sp:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_del_temp_record`(p_tbl varchar(255),  max_record smallint(6),del_count smallint(6))
BEGIN
    SET @count_query=CONCAT ("select count(auto_id) into @count_record from ",p_tbl);
    PREPARE count_record_q FROM @count_query;
    EXECUTE count_record_q;


    if @count_record>max_record then
        SET @del_query=CONCAT ("delete from ",p_tbl," order by auto_id asc limit ",del_count);
        PREPARE del_query_q FROM @del_query;
        EXECUTE del_query_q;
    end if;    
   END;
```

Comment: Define "it not work"

Comment: use **mysqli_query** instead of mysql_query

Comment: thanks is ok:  mysqli_query($link2,"CALL sp_del_temp_record('tbl_user_login_and',1880 ,10)");

Comment: sorry my flag is not true. thank s lot **gilchris** .your  answer was true. **mysql_query** not work but **mysqli_query** is ok.

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_del_temp_record`(p_tbl varchar(255),  max_record smallint(6),del_count smallint(6))
BEGIN
    SET count_query=CONCAT ("select count(auto_id) into count_record from ",p_tbl);
    PREPARE count_record_q FROM count_query;
    EXECUTE count_record_q;


    if count_record>max_record then
        SET del_query=CONCAT ("delete from ",p_tbl," order by auto_id asc limit ",del_count);
        PREPARE del_query_q FROM del_query;
        EXECUTE del_query_q;
    end if;    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: $re=mysql_query("CALL sp_del_temp_record('tbl_user_login_and',1877,10)"); 
 if($re)
  print "ok1";
 else
 {
  print  mysql_error();
 } 
result is :PROCEDURE dbname.sp_del_temp_record can't return a result set in the given context

Comment: plz declare the variables , refer this link . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932540/how-to-solve-this-error-1064-while-creating-function

Answer (score 0):

```
$thisGuy = new MySQLI(inputParamsHere);
$retVal = $thisGuy->multi_query("CALL myDB.storedProc($var1, $var2, @return1, @return2); 
select @return1 as firstValue, @return2 as secondValue;");
if ($retVal) getResultSets();
```

Try using mysqli multi_query

```
public function getResultSets() {
$retVal = array();
do {
    if ($result = $this->mysqli->store_result())
        $retVal[] = $result;
} while ($this->mysqli->next_result());
return $retVal;
```

}